# When to use $path, $dir or $file as a variable name

Tags: variables, path, naming-conventions

Obviously I know the difference between a file and a directory :)
I also know that both a file and a directory have a path.

But when writing code, what will you use when?

E.g.:

I want to clear all `*.js` files in a directory...

```
$filesystem->removeJsFiles($jsDir|$jsPath);
```

Copy an XML file...

```
$filesystem->copy($xmlFile|$xmlPath);
```

So when will you typically use $path as a variable instead of `$dir` or `$file` (or the other way around)?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to distinguish between filenames, paths and file handles I would use simply *jsDir* and *xmlFile*. Otherwise I would use *jsDirName* or *jsDirPath* and *xmlFileName* or *xmlFilePath*, and *jsDir* and *xmlFile* for file handles.